# Component form binding problem child component

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms and I have a component that receives a list.
Inside this component I go throw each item and I create a new form group.

```
export interface Detail {
  note : string;
  infos : string[]
}

@Input() details: Detail[];
 
ngOnInit(): void {
    const formArray = <UntypedFormArray>this.rootFormGroup.form.controls[this.formArrayName] as FormArray;
    formArray.clear({emitEvent: false});
    for (const detail of this.details) {
        formArray.push(
            new UntypedFormGroup({
                note: new UntypedFormControl(detail.note, [Validators.required]),
                infos: new UntypedFormArray([]),
            })
        );
    }
}



<ng-container [formArrayName]="formArrayName">
    <span *ngFor="let option of formArray.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
     {{option.note}}
     <child-info-container infos-list="???">  </child-info-container>
</ng-container>
```

This works well, the problem is that I want o create to initialize "infos" form Array inside a child component. As in HTML I am iterating throw the controllers, what is the best way to access it?

Comment: Maybe simple `option.value.infos` as input in your child component `<child-info-container` ?

Comment: But the option in ngFor is the formArray, not the list.